# Matlab : Create Rectangular Box with name

Tags: image, matlab, box

Currently, I try to draw a rectangular box around a white object with a label indicating its size.
I want create 4 categories of sizes:

1. Don't have
2. Small
3. Medium
4. Big

[image: Example of small objects]

I don't have clue how to create this.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might want to take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how this site works. Also check how to create a minimal example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Your question as it stands cannot be answered. You can edit the question to include a self-contained code example, a short explanation of what goes wrong and what you actually want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `insertObjectAnnotation`:

```
% generate image
bw = zeros(1000);
[xg,yg] = meshgrid(1:1000);
rads = 10:20:100;
for ii = 1:length(rads)
    r = rads(ii);
    c = randi([1+r,1000-r],[1,2]);
    bw = bw | ( ((xg - c(1)).^2 + (yg - c(2)).^2) < r^2);
end
% extract region properties
props = regionprops(bw,'Area','BoundingBox');
% add labels
sizes = [0,2000,6000,10000];
labels = {'tiny','small','medium','large'};
colors = autumn(numel(labels));
bw = double(bw);
for ii = 1:numel(props)
    labelidx = find(props(ii).Area > sizes,1,'last');
    bw = insertObjectAnnotation(bw,'rectangle',...
        props(ii).BoundingBox,labels{labelidx},...
        'Color',colors(labelidx,:),'FontSize',32);
end
imshow(bw);
```

[image]

**EDIT**: applying this to the OP's image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. but now i apply to image i have. Still cant

Comment: I try to apply to image i want, but still cant.

Comment: what do you mean "can't"? I applied it to your image and it worked just fine. what exactly is the problem?

Comment: thanks.now I got it. but, how u eliminate small detection.

Comment: Google it or open a new question about it